# Optimizing search functions in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I hope I'm not breaking any guidelines or anything as this is mostly a showcase of my search setup. There are a few question at the bottom. I promise.

I've made a Sencha Touch 2 PhoneGap app (which is now [live in the AppStore](https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/labblistan/id624197547?mt=8&uo=4) for iOS, Android will be ready soon).
The basic premise of the app is a (somewhat huge) searchable list (with a couple of additional filters). Thus search performance is essential.

A rundown of my search controller:
When looking at examples I found people using either a submit button or search on keyup, since the latter interested me the most this is where I started.

In the examples I found, only the keyup listener was activated, a quick fix:

```
'searchfield[itemId=searchBox]' : {
       clearicontap : 'onClearSearch',
       keyup: 'onSearchKeyUp',
       submit: 'onSubmit',
       action: 'onSubmit',
       paste: 'onSubmit',
       blur: 'onSubmit'
    }
```

Now, why are keyup and submit different you might ask?
Well, the onSubmit function just runs the search function (more on that later).
The onClearSearch just clears the filters set on the store and then adds the non search based ones back in.

The onSearchKeyUp function is where it gets interesting. Since the list is huge, searching on every single letter equals poor performance. The search field stalls while searching (especially on older devices), so while the user keeps tapping letters on the keyboard nothing shows up, while at the same time queuing up javascript and (in some cases) leading to the user tapping letters again so that when all the search functions are actually done, the input might not even be what the user intended.

I remedied this by trying to deduce when the user has finished typing. I did this by having the keyup triggering a timer, in this instance 650 ms, if another keyup event is triggered within this period, the timer is cancelled, if it runs its course it triggers the search function. This timer can of course be set higher or lower. Lower means the user has type faster for it not to search while typing. Higher means that the user will have to wait longer from their last keyup event for the actual searching to begin (perceived as lag).

Of course, there is an exception, if the keyup event is from the enter key, it searches right away. Code:

```
    onSearchKeyUp: function(searchField,e) {
    if (e.event.keyCode == 13){
       window.clearTimeout(t);
       window.timer_is_on=0;
       searchFunction();
       } else {
       doTimer();
       }
       function timedCount()
       {
       t=setTimeout(function(){timedSearch();},650);
       }
       function timedSearch()
       {
       console.log('b4 search');
       searchFunction();
       window.timer_is_on=0;
       }

       function doTimer()
       {
       if (window.timer_is_on === 0)
       {
       window.timer_is_on=1;
       timedCount();
       } else {
       window.clearTimeout(t);
       window.timer_is_on=0;
       console.log('cleared timeout');
       doTimer();
       }
       }
       }

onSubmit: function(searchField,e) {
   if (window.timer_is_on === 0)
   {
   console.log('timer was not on when done was pressed');
   } else {
   console.log('timer was on when done was pressed');
   window.clearTimeout(t);
   window.timer_is_on=0;
   searchFunction();
   }
   } else {
   searchFunction();
   },
```

So for the search function. I think I might have some room for improvement here. 
First off, I noticed that when I had scrolled down the list and searched, I could end up below the actual list content, unable to scroll up. So the first thing the search function does is scroll to top.

As I mentioned in the beginning of the post, I have some additional filters. These are toolbar buttons which basically set variables and then trigger the search function. Within the search function, filtering is done based on the variables. I combined the search and filter functions as they both needed to clear filters and add them back in.

You'll also notice a loading mask and a delay. The delay is strictly empirical, turned out that a delay of 25 ms was needed for the loading mask to actually show.

My search function code:

```
    function searchFunction() {
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
                               xtype: 'loadmask',
                               message: 'Searching'
                               });
        setTimeout(function() {
        Ext.getCmp('lablist').getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0,0);
        var searchField = Ext.getCmp('searchBox');
        queryString = searchField.getValue();
        console.log('Please search by: ' + queryString);
        var store = Ext.getStore('LabListStore');
        store.clearFilter();
        genderFilterFuncForSearch();
        ageFilterFuncForSearch();
        if(queryString){
            var thisRegEx = new RegExp(queryString, "i");
            store.filterBy(function(record) {
                           if (thisRegEx.test(record.get('Analysis'))||thisRegEx.test(record.get('Groupname'))) {
                           return true;
                           }
                           return false;
                           });
        }},25);
    }
function ageFilterFuncForSearch() {
if (ageFilter === 'A') {
    Ext.getStore('LabListStore').filter('adult', '1');
} else if (ageFilter === 'C') {
    Ext.getStore('LabListStore').filter('child', '1');
}
    Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
}


function genderFilterFuncForSearch() {
if (genderFilter === 'M') {
    Ext.getStore('LabListStore').filter('Male', '1');
} else if (genderFilter === 'F') {
    Ext.getStore('LabListStore').filter('Female', '1');
}
}
```

That's basically my search setup. As this is my first Sencha Touch project it's been sort of a trial and error based workflow but where it's at now seems pretty good.
Hopefully someone'll have a few pointers to share (and hopefully I had some that some of you hadn't thought of).

A big part of this was collected from loads of different SO posts, thanks!

I promised I would have some questions:

1. Can you clear individual filters?
2. If so, would it be better
   for performance to check which filters are set and then just
   clearing those insted of calling store.clearFilter?
3. As you can see my searchfunction uses regex, is there a way to achieve the same
   kind of search without converting it to a regex object, would it be
   better for performance?

PS. Regarding 1)- I've found one way, store.filter('field', '', true); would actually clear a filter that was set in the same way. I couldn't clear the search filter in the same way though.